# How can I open and close an SSH tunnel along with Firefox?

Tags: command-line, bash, firefox, ssh, proxy

I have a proxy server which I connect to like so

```
ssh -L 2001:localhost:8888 -N myserver.com -p 443
```

I then open up Firefox

```
firefox -p "SSHProxy"
```

(It starts Firefox configured to use port 2001).  I browse a bit, then close Firefox and then stop the tunnel.

What I would like to do is automate it: open the tunnel, then open Firefox.  When I close Firefox, I'd like to close the tunnel too.

Is this possible in a simple script?

I have tried

```
ssh -L 2001:localhost:8888 -N myserver.com -p 443 && firefox -p "SSHProxy"
```

but only the SSH bit executes, Firefox does not open.  If I reverse the order, then SSH only opens after I close Firefox.

---

With help below I have used this simplified script:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

#Start SSH
ssh -L 2001:localhost:8888 -Nf myserver.com -p 443 &

#Start Firefox
firefox -p "SSHProxy" &

#Kill the SSH port 2001 when Firefox stops
trap "ps aux | grep ssh | grep 2001 | awk '{print \$2}' | xargs kill" EXIT SIGINT SIGTERM

wait
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about creating a bash script that uses arrays to store the PID and then trap and kill them:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

ssh -L 2001:localhost:8888 -N myserver.com -p 443 &
PID[0]=$!
firefox -p "SSHProxy" &
PID[1]=$!
trap "kill ${PID[*]}" INT SIGINT        
wait
```

If you need to use a password look here for `sshpass`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937104/provide-password-to-ssh-command-inside-bash-script-without-the-usage-of-public

**EDIT:**

Run the script in terminal. Browse. When done browsing, go back to terminal and press `Ctr-C` (INT/SIGINT) the processes should be cleaned up. It seemed to work for me.

Comment: This looks promising - but the SSH connection doesn't die when I close Firefox, just stays open.  I guess the `trap` isn't catching Firefox's exit? I've not heard of `trap` before but I read a bit and tried adding even more signals `trap "kill ${PID[*]}" EXIT QUIT INT STOP TERM ERR SIGINT SIGTERM` but it still wasn't caught.

Comment: Got it - I needed to detect the PID of the SSH process differently, the PID[0] being reported in the script is wrong.  So I did this:

`trap "ps aux | grep ssh | grep 2001 | awk '{print \$2}' | xargs kill" EXIT SIGINT SIGTERM`

If you modify your post I can mark yours as answer, thanks!

Comment: @Shah I am glad that you got it working. Edited the answer, but it seemed to work for me with some minor adjustments.